# Replacing polygon within composite relationship without deleting tabular record?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, relationship-class, composite

I have a geodatabase that contains a table, a point feature class, and a polygon feature class.

Each record in the table has both a related point and a related polygon, so all one-to-one relationships. The geodatabase is currently set up with composite one-to-one relationships. My issue with this is that we sometimes need to replace the polygons with better data. If a user deletes the old polygon before adding the new one, the corresponding table record is also automatically deleted.

It is important that there is referential integrity in this dataset, but I'm wondering if it might make more sense to maintain the relationship classes as simple, and then explicitly test for referential integrity during the QAQC process. We will eventually be allowing partners to edit replicas of this database, and my concern is that this will cause some problems with users.

Is there an efficient way to replace a polygon within a composite relationshp without deleting the tabular record?

Comment: You could use 'transfer attributes' from the Spatial Adjustment toolbar http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v0000000s000000 which can also transfer geometry... this allows you to replace the existing geometry in the polygon row with the newer one without deletion, you can also transfer all or selected attributes. Does that sound like it would help? You would need to click twice interactively for each polygon in the map.. or there's update dataset http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Upgrade_Dataset/001700000178000000/ that might do what you need.